# ways to roll a die with probability and permutation

Tags: probability

how many ways can I roll a die so it is all different numbers every time?

...for instance, what is all the possibilities of rolling all 3 different numbers...

so 1 2 3, 2 3 4, etc... but 3 2 1 also counts ..

I don't understand this concept, I now the total different methods is 6 cubed, but we only need the different combinations here..

I tried 6! 5! 4! but it doesn't make sense it shouldn't be bigger than 216

Comment: Every time? There are only six numbers on a die (cubed).

Comment: yes...so how many different ways can I roll all 3 different numbers...

Comment: ooo excuse me, there are 3 die I roll at once

Comment: How could it be $6^3$? That would allow rolls such as $5,5,5$ which clearly are not different rolls.

Comment: @David, oh I didn't see that part.

Answer (score 1):

According to the original post, you want to count the ways to roll an unbiased 6-sided die $k$ times so that each roll has a distinct result, for $k\in\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$.

So for each $k$ you count the ways to select and permutate $k$ of $6$ results.

$$\begin{align}\text{count} &= \sum_{k=1}^6 {^6\mathbf P_k}
\\ & = \sum_{k=1}^6 {6\choose k}k!
\\ & = 6! \sum_{k=1}^6 \frac{1}{(6-k)!}
\end{align}$$

---

According to one of the comments, you just want to count the ways to roll an unbiased 6-sided die $3$ times so that each roll has a distinct result.  This is simply:

$$\begin{align}\text{count}_2 &= {^6\mathbf P_3}
\\ & = {6\choose 3}3!
\\ & = \frac{6!}{3!}
\end{align}$$

Comment: But I think the OP is asking for exactly $3$ rolls so the summation here would be from $3$ to $3$ and yield a result of $120$

Comment: @David I read, "for instance" as that being just one case.

Comment: I read a comment from the OP stating 3 "die" rolled at once so yes it is one case, one out of $120$.

Comment: @David, so noted

Answer (score 0):

$6 * 5 * 4 = 120$ since there are $6$ possible outcomes of the first die roll, $5$ for the 2nd roll such that it doesn't match the first, and $4$ for the third die rolls such that it doesn't match any previous rolls.  Here, we are considering $1,2,3$ (for example) as different than $3,2,1$.  If you instead don't consider those different rolls (such as you rolled all $3$ dice at once and then sorted the numbers from low to high such that $3,2,1$ would become $1,2,3$, then there are only $6 \choose 3$ = $20$ different ways to roll $3$ different numbers.